react, eas build error: "Running "npm install" in", "Could not resolve dependency"
i have a react expo project, the project works well when i use the expoGo app,
but when im trying to build my project with eas-cli,
i got some errors that i cannot solve.
this is my log:
Running "npm install" in /home/expo/workingdir/build directory
npm ERR!
code ERESOLVE
npm
ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-navigation-drawer@2.7.2
npm ERR! Found: react-native-gesture-handler@2.12.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler
npm ERR!   react-native-gesture-handler@"^2.12.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native-gesture-handler@">= 1.0.0" from @react-navigation/drawer@6.6.6
npm
ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/drawer@"^6.6.6" from the root project
npm ERR!     peerOptional @react-navigation/drawer@"^6.5.8" from expo-router@2.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/expo-router
npm ERR!       expo-router@"^2.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (@react-navigation/stack, expo-router)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-gesture-handler@"^1.0.12" from react-navigation-drawer@2.7.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-navigation-drawer
npm ERR!
react-navigation-drawer@"^2.7.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native-gesture-handler@1.10.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler
npm ERR!   peer react-native-gesture-handler@"^1.0.12" from react-navigation-drawer@2.7.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-navigation-drawer
npm ERR!     react-navigation-drawer@"^2.7.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/expo/.npm/_logs/2024-04-25T13_12_23_758Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/expo/.npm/_logs/2024-04-25T13_12_23_758Z-debug-0.log

someone had this issue?

This occurs due to dependecies conflict.
Simply run the command
npm install --force
